# Symfony 3.2, authentification and cross-site cookies

Tags: symfony, cookies, symfony-3.2

I know that Symfony 3.2 is not maintained for very long time, but it happens that my company use it.
And now we have a problem with authentifacation. We have widget that can be (and is) installed on multiple sites, so user can log in there. But database and backend code in Symfony 3.2 is stored in our site. And for authentification we use standard Symfony cookies, which are in our case cross-site.
But now Google Chrome is restricted access to cross-domain cookies which are not marked as SameSite=None. So authentification in Chrome doesn't work anymore.
I know that in Symfony 4.2 I can solve this problem by setting security parameter in security.yaml. But in Symfony 3.2 it doesn't work.
Is there any way to solve this problem except for upgrade to Symfony 4?

Answer (score 0):

*From https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/samesite-examples/blob/master/php.md*

As of PHP 7.3.0 the
[`setcookie()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) method
supports the `SameSite` attribute in its options and will accept `None` as a
valid value.

```php
// Set a same-site cookie for first-party contexts
setcookie('cookie1', 'value1', ['samesite' => 'Lax']);
// Set a cross-site cookie for third-party contexts
setcookie('cookie2', 'value2', ['samesite' => 'None', 'secure' => true]);
```

For earlier versions of PHP, you can also set the
[`header()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) directly:

```php
// Set a same-site cookie for first-party contexts
header('Set-Cookie: cookie1=value1; SameSite=Lax', false);
// Set a cross-site cookie for third-party contexts
header('Set-Cookie: cookie2=value2; SameSite=None; Secure', false);
```

For Session Cookie , you can set into [`session_set_cookie_params`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php)  method.
PHP 7.3.0 introduced new attributes for samesite.

```php
if (PHP_VERSION_ID >= 70300) { 
session_set_cookie_params([
    'lifetime' => $cookie_timeout,
    'path' => '/',
    'domain' => $cookie_domain,
    'secure' => $session_secure,
    'httponly' => $cookie_httponly,
    'samesite' => 'Lax'
]);
} else { 
session_set_cookie_params(
    $cookie_timeout,
    '/; samesite=Lax',
    $cookie_domain,
    $session_secure,
    $cookie_httponly
);
}
```

There are third-party packages, such as [delight-im/PHP-Cookie](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Cookie), which supports the `SameSite` attribute and the `None` value (since v3.2) on PHP 5.4.0+.